# How re move Double quotes with in the double Quotes in python

Tags: python, arrays

we are getting huge file every day around 500 Mb file and in the file we getting double quotes with in the Double quotes and it's semicolon delimited.

how we can remove and re create the file to process in python Script, Can you please help me anyone.

How we can remove double quotes with in the double quotes form the file.

Source Input:
"000013";"N";"WOUGA";"Y";"N";"N";"EUGENE "A" WOODS";"DO "NOT" USE" (ACTIVE IN CONCUR)";"8 "LONGHORN" HOLLOW";

OUTPUT:
"000013";"N";"WOUGA";"Y";"N";"N";"EUGENE A WOODS";"DO NOT USE" (ACTIVE IN CONCUR)";"8 LONGHORN HOLLOW";

Comment: Have you tried the `csv` module?

Comment: And how exactly should it be determined whether a `"` ends the string or if it is just a `"` within a string?

Comment: no Mark i am sure how do it.

Comment: Zvone  The  data start start with codes with end with quotes with ; Delimited Example "000013";" Mike"

Answer (score -1):

There's likely a more elegant solution out there. However, it looks like your string is delimited by a semicolon. So, splitting the string by the semicolon and looping over the values is the easiest/dirtiest solution for me.

```
input = """
"000013";"N";"WOUGA";"Y";"N";"N";"EUGENE "A" WOODS";"DO "NOT" USE" (ACTIVE IN CONCUR)";"8 "LONGHORN" HOLLOW";"
""".replace("\n","")
print(input)

split = input.split(";")

output = []
for item in split:
    length = len(str(item))
    if length > 0 and item != '"': # only append to output row if not null
        # print('"' + item.replace('"','') + '"')
        formatted_item = str('"' + item.replace('"','') + '"') # replace any inner quotes
        output += [formatted_item]

output = ';'.join(output)
output = output + ";"
print(output)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the ode, when i running the code through the file it's remove starting double Quotes and adding at the end. 000013";"N";"WOUGA";"Y";"N";"N";"EUGENE A WOODS";"DO "NOT USE (ACTIVE IN CONCUR)";"8 "LONGHORN HOLLOW";" how should able to handle. if any data doesn't have double quotes how should able to add it.